# RDD SUM on Lists alternative

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this contrived example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("A", List(1, 1)), 
                              ("B", List(2, 2, 2, 200)), 
                              ("C", List(3, 3))))
```

and can do this to tally the overall sum of the `RDD`:

```
rdd.map(_._2.sum).sum
```

or

```
rdd.flatMapValues(identities).values.sum
```

Can I sum overall taking into account there is a `List`, `Array`, etc. in a 1-step process? Or are these two approaches the basics of overall summing that need necessarily to be a two step process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my understanding both your solutions are right.

There are some other options however. For instance, here is an elegant way of doing the same:

```
rdd.flatMap(_._2).sum
```